# What's the correct way to handle a path that could either be a drive letter or a path that gets joined to something else?

Tags: rust

Using the following program:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Path::new("P:").join("A_B_C\\D\\E\\F\\G.hij"));
}
```

POSIX will give you:

```
"P:/A_B_C\\D\\E\\F\\G.hij"
```

But Windows will give you:

```
"P:A_B_C\\D\\E\\F\\G.hij"
```

The latter isn't considered to be the intended path, at least by `std::fs::copy`.

For the same of an example:

```
fn my_function(p: &Path) -> PathBuf {
    p.join("Temp")
}
```

Comment: Could you specify what the correct output would look like on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that when you specify drive letter without trailing slash symbol, Windows API interpret it as a relative path to the current directory on the drive. I.e. `P:` and `P:\` could reference to different locations, and `P:file.txt` is a valid path and means `P:\current\dir\file.txt`. You could verify it by change directory and call from command prompt `dir P:` and `dir P:\`.

If you are sure that you want to interpret "P:" as a root path then you probably should manually detect it and add root slash, but I believe it is a bad practice.

For strictly interpret path prefix and build an absolute path prefix you could use [Path::canonicalize()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.canonicalize) method, but please keep in mind that it works only for actually existent drive/path in the target OS.

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn canonical_join<P: AsRef<Path>>(a: P, b: P) -> PathBuf {
    let a = a.as_ref();
    a.canonicalize()
    .unwrap_or(PathBuf::from(a))
    .join(b)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", canonical_join("C:", "dir\\file.ext").display());
    println!("{}", canonical_join("C:\\", "dir\\file.ext").display());
    println!("{}", canonical_join("C:/", "dir\\file.ext").display());
}
```

Comment: The downside I see to this is that canonicalize tends to insert \\?\, which has caused me problems in the past. However, in spite of this, I think this does address the issue (not a critique of the answer, more of things that don't support canonicalize).